# Why do singletons use a function that returns an object instead of a simple initializing function?

Tags: php, design-patterns, singleton

On this site and others, I always see singletons written like this:

```
<?php

Class Singleton {
    private static $code = null;
    private static $instance = null;
    
    private function __construct() {
        self::$code = 'some_expensive_operation';
    }
    
    public static function getInstance() {
        if ( is_null(self::$instance) ) {
            self::$instance = new Singleton();
        }
     
        return self::$instance;
    }
    
    public static function useCode() {
        echo self::$code;
    }
}

// to use
$object1 = Singleton::getInstance();
$object1::useCode();

?>
```

But wouldn't it make more sense to write them like this, with a regular initializing function instead of a constructor?

```
<?php

Class Singleton {
    private static $code = null;
    
    public static function initialize() {
        if ( is_null(self::$code) ) {
            self::$code = 'some_expensive_operation';
        }
    }
    
    public static function useCode() {
        echo self::$code;
    }
}

Singleton::initialize();

// to use
Singleton::useCode();

?>
```

I'm drawn to the second example because using it only requires one line and no throwaway variable. It seems much cleaner.

Comment: Well, `echo` isn't really a realistic usage of the result of creating a singleton. It's normally an object (e.g. a classic one is a single database connection object) which is then passed round the application code to be used for various purposes, such as calling functions from it. So realistically it still needs assigning to a variable outside the singleton class in 99% of cases.

Comment: Also you don't want the `initialize()` function to be able to be called repeatedly without checking if an instance already exists - otherwise it's not a singleton anymore, it's a factory potentially churning out multiple instances of the same class. So I'd argue your second example is a) over-simplistic and b) not implementing the pattern adequately.

Comment: The second one is not a true singleton because the constructor can still be used.  It also doesn't check if the Object is already initialized which will cause the static variable to be overwritten each time it's used with a new instance.  So you may be drawn to the second one, but it's not coded properly.   Preferable the `__clone` function would also be private to prevent cloning the singlton.  Which is not present in either one.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Isn't the idea of a singleton that only one instance will ever exist? So why not use the class itself as the instance rather than having the class return an instance? That's basically what the initialize function is doing.

I could have done a better job on the example code. In reality I would make sure the initializer is only ran once, just as the traditional pattern ensures the constructor is only ran once. I edited to reflect this.

Comment: `why not use the class itself as the instance rather than having the class return an instance`...because usually the singleton class is wrapper to create an instance of another class (e.g. a database connection object, as I mentioned before) and in doing so to ensure that only one such instance is ever created. If the thing you're wanting to single is completely custom and not reliant on another class, your idea might work but that's not always the case. So, you could do it your way sometimes for very simple cases, but not every time - it depends.

Comment: @jstallings - because for the class to return the same instance every time, it must be stored inside a static variable with is shared with all instances.  Calling the constructor will create a "new" instance, which is not what the purpose of a singleton is.  Therefore the only option is to use a static method to get access to the static instance of the class.  Which will return the same object, if written correctly, as I pointed out the second one is not written correctly.

Comment: `That's basically what the initialize function is doing`...no, your example initialize() function doesn't create an instance of Singleton, it just assigns a value to one static variable. That's fine if all you want to single is one, specific, one-time operation, but again that's often not what's really needed.

Comment: I see you changed the second one, however it's still not correct because it doesn't return an instance of the class.  Which means you can never use it, without using only static functions.  So you  see if you fix that, it's essentially the first one, which is the only way it works.   In order to access public methods that are non-static you will need to return the object ( instance of the class ).

Comment: "because usually the singleton class is wrapper to create an instance of another class" - the initializer function could do this just as easily, couldn't it? Only one instance will ever exist, so why not assign the database connection object to a static variable that'll be used every time? Returning that object into a throwaway variable just seems like a wasted step no matter how I look at it, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: "Which means you can never use it, without using only static functions" - what's the problem with that?

Comment: The problem with that is then all your internal variables must also be static and all your functions must be static, so you don't need an instance of that object, which means you don't need a singleton.  Which means we are not having a conversation about singltons but static classes.  Static classes by definition cannot maintain an internal state.  Calling just static functions, you have no idea if say a database connection was properly made or not, without testing it.

Comment: `why not assign the database connection object to a static variable that'll be used every time`...that's exactly what most singletons do. I actually don't think the example in your first snippet is really reflective of how a singleton class would usually work, either.

Comment: @ADyson - I disagree, the only static variable inside a singleton should be the instance of the singleton.  By using a static variable for a database connection, especially if it's public you cannot guarantee that it was properly initialized without testing it.  The idea with a singleton is that you can guarantee that because you need to get an instance of an object that can maintain an internal state.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix DB connection is just an example (and people often say it isn't a good one - these days we would mostly rather use DI). But I don't know if you've misunderstood what I mean, or I've misunderstood what you mean, because I thought `the only static variable inside a singleton should be the instance of the singleton` was exactly what I'd proposed.

Comment: `why not assign the database connection object to a static variable that'll be used every time...that's exactly what most singletons do`  -- I was inferring you meant that they literally stored the connection in a static variable.   I would strongly suggest that the only properties in a singleton that are static is the singleton itself,  in the case of the database you could create a new singleton for each database, that is the downside of a singleton handling a database, you cannot use more then one DB at a time, however I like to call it a MultiTon.... lol

Comment: I actually have a lot of experience writing and using singletons, I have a library on GitHub and Composer that consists of a trait and an interface that makes making them a easy, including a mutliton which is a singleton that stores an array of instances based on a key you use when getting an instance.  Such as a Database name.   https://github.com/ArtisticPhoenix/Pattern  for example `DB::I('members')` would get an instance connected to the 'members' Database.  Maybe `DB::I('wordpress')` gets the wordpress DB instance etc...

Comment: Some MVC libraries do a similar thing by storing an instance of the class in a globally accessible array such as  Laravel's `app->singleton($class, $object)` - which is essentially the same thing, but it is still DependancyInjection.  These have a downside that you can only access the singleton after it's initialized.   By being "self-contained"  you don't have to worry about when that happens, you can provide it with a database name and a configuration file that will give it all the information it needs anytime it's called to make the connection.  Another example, Queuing system RabbitMq

Comment: "you have no idea if say a database connection was properly made or not, without testing it" - this test has to be performed regardless of whether it's initialized using a constructor or a regular function, right? I still don't quite see what the difference is in practice, but obviously I'm not the most experienced so you two have given me a lot to think about and look into. Thanks again.

Comment: There is a reason why we use objects instead of static util classes. How would you want to use a mock object instead of that singleton in a test case if you implement it as a static util class as you suggest?

Comment: @jstallings - No, because in the case of a static utility you would need check if some internal property to it was set.  But you are not enforced to do it.  With an instance you have no choice but to first get it and it does all the checking internally so you don't have to do it in code every time.  That is how it guarantees that the instance has the proper connection, because you cannot use it without it being so.  Just because you can do something dosn't mean you are forced to do it.  What if 12 months later you forget you had to do that first.

Comment: I get it now... you can perform error checking in the getInstance function, the use of which is enforced, while in the static class you'd have to remember to run an error checking function before use or implement error checking in every public function. That's a huge selling point for the singleton design. I really appreciate y'all bearing with me.